# Pass Data from one page to another

Tags: html, jsp

I have a page consisting of many anchor tags and when each link is clicked an associated data has to be sent to the target page and is to be displayed in the target page. Here is the snapshot of the code

```
<a href="target.html?Some%data">click1</a>
<a href="target.html?Some%other%data">click2</a>
```

and so on...i should be able to display Some data when i click on clik1 and Some other data when i click on click2

Comment: "display" how? Can you use Javascript? Can you use a server side language?

Comment: i should simply hold it in a variable..actual i have two jsp pages...source.jsp and target.jsp

Comment: did you try: url?a=something&b=something and using GET methods!

Comment: i am not using any form so GET doesnot work for me

Comment: This is impossible with alone HTML. In the future, don't forget to specify in the question and tags the server side language / view technology you're using. I've added the `[jsp]` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> actual i have two jsp pages...source.jsp and target.jsp

Pass them as GET request parameters in a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in `source.jsp`:

```
<a href="target.jsp?data=some%20data">click1</a>
<a href="target.jsp?data=some%20other%20data">click2</a>
```

<sup>*(note that a space is to be [URL-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as `%20`, not as `%`)*</sup>

And use EL `${param}` to access them in the `target.jsp`:

```
<p>The parameter with name "data" has the value ${param.data}</p>
```

To prevent [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html), preferably use [JSTL's `c:out`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) to redisplay user-controlled input:

```
<p>The parameter with name "data" has the value <c:out value="${param.data}" /></p>
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 5 tutorial - Implicit objects in EL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij)
- [JSP tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)

Comment: hi sir,  i did not understand how to pass them as GET request parameters in the query string...could be please elaborate...sorry as i am a newbie to web technologies

Comment: Read the code example. I've already demonstrated it for you. The query string is the part after `?` in URL. The name-value pairs are represented by `name=value`. You can specify multiple pairs and concatenate them by `&`. See also the wikipedia link.

Comment: one last question...how do i pass values in source.jsp

Comment: Just exactly as in my answer. `<a href="target.jsp?data=some%20data">click1</a>`. The `data` is the parameter name. The `some%20data` is the parameter value. You can change this part. In the target page, the parameter value is available by `${param.data}`.

Comment: sorry sir, thanks for spending ur valuable time...but i am unable to understand what u say...may be as i am a newbie...thanks for ur help

Comment: Just copypaste the code pieces unchanged in the respective files and experiment with it.